# An expression that vanishes over every field

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29066/traababb-traabbab-for-22-matrices), Jack Schmidt asks to prove a certain identity for $2\times 2$ matrices A and B.

In fact he asks to show that tr(AABABB−AABBAB) = 0. In an answer by user7406, he shows that 3 times this expression must be 0, solving the problem at least when the characteristic of the ground field isn't 3.
In a comment by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez he tells us a computercalculation show that it is in fact identically zero.

This made me wonder whether or not this is a surprise. I think the proper way to state the problem is as follows:

Let $\varphi \colon \mathbb Z\langle x_1,\dots x_n\rangle\to \mathbb Q [x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the morphism from the free non-commutative ring over these variables to the polynomialring. Let $\Phi \colon \mathbb Z\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle \to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the corresponding morphism by sending every element to 'itself' the ususal way.

Here are my questions:

- Is it true that if $\varphi(x)=0$ then $\Phi(x) = 0$? My guess is it is because one can construct $\psi$ such that $\Phi = \psi\circ \varphi$.
- Does this indeed settle the original problem for characteristic 3 from the solution by user7406, thereby bypassing von Neumann or am I really missing something?

[I first asked this question in a comment to the post by user7406, but I deleted that because I didn't want to hijack the other question.]

Comment: I didn't get the von Neumann reference until you explained it. :)

Comment: What is $k$? I don't see how you can construct a nonzero map $\psi\colon \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ unless $k$ has characteristic zero, which would make it hard to get a $\psi$ if, say, $k=\mathbb{F}_3$ (for which $\Phi$ still makes sense).

Comment: @Arturo $k$ would be any field. I think you're right, the $\mathbb Q$ should perhaps be $\mathbb Z$ for this to hold.

Comment: Yes: the image of $\varphi$ lies inside $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ anyway, and $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is initial in the class of polynomial rings in $n$ variables, so you'll want to replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$. I'm trying to write up a reply as I type this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the image of $\varphi$ lies inside of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, you can replace $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ with $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (since the image vanishes in the latter if and only if it vanishes in the former).

Any map from $\mathbb{Z}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ to a commutative ring factors uniquely through $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ by the universal property of the polynomial ring.

Explicitly: given any ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$, where $R$ and $S$ are commutative, and given any elements $s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\overline{f}\colon R[x]\to S$ such that $\overline{f}(r)=f(r)$ for all $r\in R$ and $\overline{f}(x_i) = s_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

In particular, if $\Phi$ is any map from $\mathbb{Z}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ to a commutative ring $S$, then $\Phi(x_i)$ determines a unique homomorphism $\psi\colon\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to S$ with $\psi(x_i)=\Phi(x_i)$ and $\psi(1) = \Phi(1)$. This map makes a commuting triangle with the quotient map $\varphi$. Hence we get $\Phi=\psi\circ\varphi$, as you suggest in point (1) (after replacing $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, if $\Phi$ is any map from $\mathbb{Z}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ to a commutative ring $S$, then necessarily $\mathrm{ker}(\varphi)\subseteq\mathrm{ker}(\Phi)$, which answers your first question.

(Or, you can think about the "multidegree" of a monomial in $\mathbb{Z}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ which only counts the total exponent of each variable; an element of $\mathbb{Z}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ lies in the kernel of $\varphi$ if and only if it is a sum of "homogeneous terms", i.e., same multidegree for all monomials, where the coefficients add up to $0$. Any such homogeneous term will also lie in the kernel of any $\Phi$, since the image is commutative).

But I'm not sure why you would need to go through this for your second question: $\mathrm{trace}(AABABB-AABBAB)$ can be written as a (commutative) polynomial in the $8$ variables that form the entries of $A$ and $B$, with integer coefficients; i.e., an element of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (not of $\mathbb{Z}\langle A,B\rangle$, because we are looking at the trace, not the product itself). If $3$ times this expression is $0$ *as an element of* $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then this expression is itself $0$ simply because $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is an integral domain. And from there, you get that the corresponding expresssion is also identically zero over any field, because it is zero in the initial polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

That is, the lack of commutativity between the matrices does not matter here, because the expression we are looking for, the trace, is computed in terms of the *coefficients* of the matrices via commutative (though complicated) operations.

E.g., if you were talking about the trace of $AB-BBA$, you would have
$$\begin{align*}
A&=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}\right),\\
B&=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{array}\right),\\
\mathrm{trace}(AB - BBA) &= \mathrm{trace}(AB) - \mathrm{trace}(BBA)\\
&= \Bigr(a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}\Bigr) \\
&\qquad\mathop{+} \Bigl( (b_{11}^2+b_{12}b_{21})a_{11} + (b_{11}b_{12}+b_{12}b_{22})a_{21}\\
&\qquad\quad\mathop{+} (b_{21}b_{11}+b_{22}b_{21})a_{12} + (b_{21}b_{12}+b_{22}^2)a_{22}\Bigr)
\end{align*}$$
This is a *polynomial* in $\mathbb{Z}[a_{11},\ldots,b_{22}]$, with commuting variables; not an element of $\mathbb{Z}\langle a_{11},\ldots,b_{22}\rangle$.

Note that you cannot interpret the trace map as a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\langle A,B\rangle$ to something, because the trace is not a ring homomorphism: the trace of the product is not the product of the traces.

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean that I don't need to go around $\mathbb Z\langle a_{11},\dots,b_{22}\rangle$ to get what I want. I guess I did that because if you state it this way, what it comes down to is that "0 in Z[...] is mapped to 0 in k[...]". Which is, well, so obvious that I wouldn't believe it is just that.

Comment: One *can* look at the trace as a map $\mathbb Z\langle A,B\rangle\to k$ by defining it on monomials as the composition $\mathbb Z\langle A,B\rangle\to M_n(k)\stackrel{\operatorname{tr}}\to k$, with the first map the obvious one. This is what was meant, I guess. This composition is not a ring map, of course.

Comment: @Mariano: Right: I should change "map" to "ring homomorphism" in that final paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly true that if you prove a polynomial identity over $\mathbb{Z}$, then you get the same identity over any commutative ring whatsoever for free: there is a well-defined homomorphism $\psi_A : \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, and in particular, $\psi_\mathbb{C}$ is injective, so even if you use complex numbers in your proof, it will still be valid (and the same holds even when you pass to the algebraic completion of $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ itself).

As for the original problem, it is just a matter of proving a certain polynomial identity in 8 variables, so this method is indeed applicable.